# Using INNER JOIN in DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to the following condition: If any loan in Loans table has OutstandingAmount < 0, delete all the relevant information in the database.
I have to do it in a single command and hence, I have tried using INNER JOIN:

```
DELETE A, B, C, D, E
FROM Loans AS T1
INNER JOIN Payments T2 ON T1.LoanID = T2.LoanID
INNER JOIN Repayments T3 ON T1.LoanID = T3.LoanID
INNER JOIN Histories T4 ON T1.LoanID = T4.LoanID
INNER JOIN LoanRequests T5 ON T1.RequestDate = T5.RequestDate AND T1.BID = T5.BID
INNER JOIN Commits T6 ON T1.RequestDate = T6.requestDate AND T1.BID = T6.BID
WHERE T1.OutstandingAmount < 0
```

However, this command gives me syntax error at "DELETE A, B," and I'm not even sure will this work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In SQL Server, you can only delete from one table at a time.  Perhaps you want cascading foreign key relationships instead.

Comment: Or use Magic tables (no joking, google it)

Comment: What are the A, B, C, D and E? They are not tables... are they columns?

Comment: @Veljko89 huh, I never heard them called "magic tables" before. After looking it up, I understand what you're referring to, I've just never heard them called that.

Answer (score 4):

As Gordon Linoff wrote in his comment, you can only delete from one table in each delete statement.

You basically have 2 options:

1. Use on delete cascade in your foreign keys (that's probably the best
   thing to do)
2. Use a delete statement for each table, but wrap the entire delete process in a transaction.

Adding On delete cascade to your foreign keys means drop and re-create them:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Loans
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_Loans_Payments; 

ALTER TABLE dbo.Loans
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Loans_Payments FOREIGN KEY (LoanID) REFERENCES Payments(LoanID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Using a transaction to wrap individual delete statements:

```
BEGIN TRASACTION

BEGIN TRY

DELETE c
FROM Commits 
INNER JOIN Loans l ON l.RequestDate = c.RequestDate 
WHERE l.OutstandingAmount < 0

DELETE lr
FROM LoanRequests lr
INNER JOIN Loans l ON l.RequestDate = lr.RequestDate 
WHERE l.OutstandingAmount < 0

-- more of the same...

DELETE 
FROM Loans
WHERE OutstandingAmount < 0

COMMIT TRANSACTION

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have adopted both your methods (ON DELETE CASCADE and TRANSACTION). With ON DELETE CASCADE, I have successfully reduced the DELETE statements to only 2 and insert them into TRANSACTION. It works !! Thank you once again.